# Entity Framework Code First - Relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am searching for the best way to do the next relation.

I have 2 entities, `User` and `PartnerUser`

```
public class User
{
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool Validate { get; set; }        
}

public class PartnerUser
{
    public int IdPartnerUser { get; set; }        
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

One user can have many partners (one to many) and Partner only can have one user **but at the same time the Partner is an User** (and this is my problem)

In Entity Framework what is the best way to create this relation?

Comment: "at the same time the Partner is an User", this is not possible. Is it a Partner or an User? Are you sure they are different entities?

Comment: Yes, to Partner is one User related to another User. Always one partner need to be a user. In Spanish this type of relation is called ("reciproca") i don't know the name in inglish. Its similar to relation of Employees and Boss (direct boss, only one boss). One boss is an employe of the company and is a boss for some employees so is a employe and boss at the same time.
In "reciproca" to solve this uses one field in the same table to do the relation.
I'm need to do a diferent entity because the logic is diferent from one entity to other.
Best regards.

Comment: Hi Camilo,
Your solution work's perfect,
The "reciprocal" spanish name is as you said to me the self-joined.

If you post the comment as an answer, I validate it as correct

Thank you so much.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't have two entities here, only one - `User`. You can do a self-join as a one-to-many non-required relationship, so a `User` can have a `Partner` (many-to-one side) or `Partners` (one-to-many side):

```
public class User
{
    // I changed this to UserId to keep with naming conventions, 
    // it should otherwise be just Id, but not IdUser
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public int? PartnerId { get; set; }

    public User Partner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Partners { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You acpecting something like this...

```
public class User
{      
  public int IdUser { get; set; }

  public string UserName { get; set; }

  public bool Validate { get; set; } 

  public int? PartnerId { get; set; }

  public User Partner { get; set; }

  public ICollection<User> PartnerUsers{ get; set;}       
}
```

Comment: This has two mistakes: 1, `PartnerId` should be nullable or otherwise you could never insert the first item to the table. 2. The `ForeignKeyAttribute` should point to the other side of the relationship, `Partner` in this case, not `PartnerId`.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me @CamiloTerevinto